# how to open the jsp page irrespective of path variable passed?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

here is my controller method for emaillogin.jsp

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/quickstart/email")

    public String viewQuickStartEmailForm(@ModelAttribute(value = "quickbean") 
    QuickStartBean quickbean,BindingResult result,Model model) {

        try {       

email=quickbean.getEmail();
model.addAttribute("email", email);

model.addAttribute("quickstartdatabean",new QuickStartBean() );


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "quickstart/emaillogin";
    }
```

Here is my controller method for page invitation.jsp

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/quickstart/invite" )

    public String viewQuickStartInviteForm(@ModelAttribute(value = "quickbean") 
    QuickStartBean quickbean,BindingResult result,Model model {

        try {                   
inviteEmailEncrypted=getMD5(quickbean.getInviteeEmail());
address="http://localhost:8090/QuickStartConsulting/quickstart/email?key=";
model.addAttribute("inviteEmailEncrypted", inviteEmailEncrypted);
model.addAttribute("address", address);     
model.addAttribute("quickstartdatabean",new QuickStartBean() );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return "quickstart/invitation";
    }
```

invitation.jsp which only generates a url

```
http://localhost:8090/QuickStartConsulting/quickstart/email?key=d58e3582afa99040e27b92b13c8f2280
```

Now i want to open my emailogin.jsp page  when user passes the above url. Emaillogin page is the my first page.'
Invitation page and emaillogin page are not connected through action .
How can i do it?

Comment: use `redirect:/url` or use flash attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `redirect` to return to other url

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/quickstart/invite" )
public ModelAndView viewQuickStartEmailForm(@ModelAttribute(value = "quickbean")  QuickStartBean quickbean,BindingResult result,Model model) {
     inviteEmailEncrypted=getMD5(quickbean.getInviteeEmail());
     address="http://localhost:8090/QuickStartConsulting/quickstart/email?key="+inviteEmailEncrypted;
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/"+address);
}
```

One more option is to use *FlashAttributes*.